# LIBGDX: Shoot a bullet using mouse position

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to shoot a bullet towards my mouse position but I think that my math is probably wrong since the position the bullets travel to isn't the right one.
Here's my code

```
Vector2 bulletDirection = new Vector2(screenX - player.getX(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - (player.getY() - screenY)).nor();
bullet.setPosiion(player.getX(), player.getY());
bullet.translate(bulletDirection.x * flightSpeed, bulletDirection.y * flightSpeed);
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? The "bullet" object is my current bullet sprite

Comment: Where do your bullets go instead? The more details you can give us about the symptoms, the better we can narrow down the cause. I do notice the order of terms in the y component of your Vector2 looks unusual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using `Gdx.graphics.getHeight()` to change orientation of vertical axis from recieved click. If this is the case following code should work correctly:

```
Vector2 bulletDirection = new Vector2(screenX - player.getX(), (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - screenY) - player.getY()).nor();
```

Also there is better way using `unproject` described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18555705/7361496) as it will later solve problems with zooming and moving camera:

```
Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3(screenX, screenY, 0);
Vector3 unprojectedPos = camera.unproject(touchPos);
Vector2 bulletDirection = new Vector2(unprojectedPos.x - player.getX(), unprojectedPos.y - player.getY()).nor();
```

Comment: Thank you so much!